# How to change the cursor style when hovered over Google Chart API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I've done here is I can change the cursor style to pointer when hovered over the column **with CSS**. However, I don't know to do the same path **with Javascript** and **events.addListener**

- Summary: Change the cursor style

  1. With *CSS* (**Done**)
  2. With *Javascript* (**Not yet**)
  3. With *events.addListener* (**Not yet**)

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/GM9sb/)</kbd>**

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="chart_div" style="width: 350px; height: 350px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="table_div" style="width: 350px; height: 350px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
chart1();
chart2();

function chart1() {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'USD'],
            ['RSC Company', 1264383.00]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'RSC Shipment Weekly: 27',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
};

function chart2() {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'Conts'],
            ['RSC Company', 10]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'RSC Shipment Weeky: 27',
            colors: ['#FF0000']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: since you can change the cursor with CSS, Why do you want to change it with Javascript?

Comment: @ImranBughio: As the div tag `runas="server"` so the `id` attribute for that `div` is not solid and doesn't work with the CSS anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**CHECK THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/GM9sb/5/)

```
       google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
                 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', uselessHandler2);
         google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', uselessHandler3);
        chart.draw(data, options);

function uselessHandler2() {
 $('#chart_div').css('cursor','pointer')
  }  
        function uselessHandler3() {
 $('#chart_div').css('cursor','default')
  }
```

use this...

Comment: Any way to get it to do it on the axis labels as well?

Answer (score 1):

## Alternate approach to change mouse cursor

For those who prefer not to use jQuery and want to set the style manually instead of using a CSS class you can always get the the Id attribute by using the document.getElementById() method such as illustrated below just make sure you are accessing the correct parent div:

```
google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', mouseHandlerPointer);                 
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', mouseHandlerDefault);

function mouseHandlerPointer() {
   document.getElementById('chart_div').style.cursor = 'pointer';
 }  

function mouseHandlerDefault() {
   document.getElementById('chart_div').style.cursor = 'default';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Way to get it to do it on the axis labels only:

```
var element = document.getElementById('<?= $chartId; ?>');
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(element);
var $element = jQuery(element);
chart.draw(data, options);

$element.on('mouseover', 'g', function () {
    if (this.logicalname && this.logicalname.match(/vAxis/))
        $element.css('cursor', 'pointer');
}).on('mouseout', 'g', function () {
    $element.css('cursor', 'default');
});
```

Change `vAxis` to `hAxis` to make it working for the horizontal axis.